# Issue with js if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code but the if condition never returns true. I am trying to change between bg for widescreen and normal screens.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $(window).width;
    var height = $(window).height;
    var ratio = height / width;

    if(ratio >= 0.8) {
        $('body.preview').attr('style','background-image:url(images/_bg.jpg)');
    } else {
        $('body.preview').attr('style','background-image:url(images/bg.jpg)');
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(window).width` and `$(window).height` are _functions_ so you're doing `fn1 / fn2 = NaN`

Comment: Looks hard to imagine you didn't try to debug it on your side before posting it as a question...

Comment: did you try reading jQuery documentation? http://api.jquery.com/height/ did you try using `console.log(width);`?

Answer (score 3):

[`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`.heigth()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) are jquery functions not properties.

Try,

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
var ratio = height / width;
```

Comment: Why would you use `$(window).width()` when you can just do `innerWidth`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: `window.innerWidth -> 1920; $(window).width(); -> 1903;` They're not the same.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i am just trying to point out what op has done wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

`width` and `height` are methods, so you need to call them:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
```

Moreover, to set the style you'd better use `.css` method:

```
$('body.preview').css('background-image', 'url(images/bg.jpg)');
```

Comment: he might be aiming at overwriting whole inline style instead of just adding `background-image` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parenthesis:

```
var width = $(window).width(); //width should be width()
var height = $(window).height(); //height should be height()
```

Answer (score 0):

You omitted the parenthesises of the methods (width and height)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var ratio = height / width;

    if(ratio >= 0.8)
    {
        $('body.preview').attr('style','background-image:url(images/_bg.jpg)');
    }
    else
    {
        $('body.preview').attr('style','background-image:url(images/bg.jpg)');
    }

});
```